# Allow non-administrative Windows users to enumerate users and change ACL of remote samba/SMB/CIFS-server

Tags: windows-10, samba, freenas

I use a Samba 4.10.13 server on FreeNAS. I want to change the ACL and therefore enumerate the users of the FreeNAS. I noticed that this requires the client(!) to have administrative rights on the client machine (windows 10) in order to list the remote (FreeNAS-)users. Is there some fine-grained right that can be granted to non-administrative users to allow this operation without giving full administrative rights?

Edit: both systems are standalone, no AD environment.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this Windows 10 Home or Pro?

Comment: pro -----------